# Probability newspaper company

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve this task but I'm obviously stuck. Will anyone help me solve it?

In a certain company three newspapers are published. 20% of the population read A, 16% read B, 14% read C, 8% read A and B, 5% read A and C, 4% read B and C, and 2% read all 3 newspapers. A person is selected at random.

**a)** none of the papers
**b)** at least one of the papers
**c)** exactly one of the papers
**d)** A or B (or both)
**e)** A, given that the person reads at least one paper
**f)** C, given that the person reads either A or B (or both).

Comment: for part a solve $1-[P(A\cup B\cup C) = P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A \cap B) - P(B \cap C) - P(A  \cap C) + P(A  \cap B  \cap C)]$

Comment: You should show what you have tried, and where you are getting stuck or confused.

Comment: Try drawing a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of answer you are looking for. The easiest way to solve this is to make a Venn Diagram and fill in the values as required. This gives you probabilities quickly.

To solve this you need to look at intersection and union of events, and need to know the general formula
$$ \mathbb{P}(A\cup B\cup C) = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) + \mathbb{P}(C) - \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) -+ \mathbb{P}(B\cap C)- \mathbb{P}(C\cap A)+ \mathbb{P}(A\cap B\cap C). $$

Let $A$ denote the event that a person reads newspaper $A$. Set similar defintions for $B$ and $C$. It is given to you that,

$\mathbb{P}(A) = 0.20,\ \mathbb{P}(B) = 0.16,\ \mathbb{P}(C) = 0.14,\ \mathbb{P}(A\cap B) = 0.08,\ \mathbb{P}(A\cap C) = 0.05,\ \mathbb{P}(B\cap B) = 0.04,\ \mathbb{P}(A\cap B\cap C) = 0.02$

Now, calculate these by yourself.

a) Probability that the person reads none of the newspapers is the even given by *complement* of the event of reading any one of the news papers. Thus, if $E_1$ is this event, then
$$ \mathbb{P}(E_1) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(A\cup B\cup C) = 1 - (0.20+0.16+0.14-0.08-0.05-0.04+0.02) = 1 - 0.35 = 0.65$$ from the definition given above.

I will only mention the events now.

b) At least one of the newspapers means, either A or B or C, is the event $$\mathbb{P}(A\cup B \cup C) = 0.35.$$ Thus, answer is which you calculated above.

c) Exactly one of the papers implies the event $$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B^c\cap C^c) + \mathbb{P}(A^c\cap B^c\cap C) + \mathbb{P}(A^c\cap B\cap C^c) = 0.22$$

d) $A$ or $B$ ( or both) is the event $A\cup B$. Thus, the probability is
$$ \mathbb{P}(A\cup B) = 0.20 + 0.16 - 0.08 = 0.28.$$ This is a little ambiguous.

e) Conditional probability. This is
$$ \mathbb{P}(A| A\cup B\cup C) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A\cap (A\cup B\cup C)}{\mathbb{P}(A\cup B\cup C)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(A\cup B\cup C)} = 0.20 / 0.35 = 4/7 = 0.571428.$$

f) Similar to above you have the probability,
$$ \mathbb{P}(C | A\cup B) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(C)}{\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)} = 0.14/0.28 = 1/2 = 0.5.$$

Answer (score 1):

> In a certain company three newspapers are published. 20% of the population read A, 16% read B, 14% read C, 8% read A and B, 5% read A and C, 4% read B and C, and 2% read all 3 newspapers.

Hint

First of all, Gerry Myerson's comment hits the nail on the head.

Consider that with 3 newspapers, there are $2^3$ categories, re a person does or does not read each of the 3 newspapers.  To solve, you must assign an explicit percentage to each of the 8 categories.  Then, everything falls into place and you can easily answer all of the questions.

You can actually construct the **arithmetic equivalent** of the Venn diagram merely by taking the information and **working backwards**.

2% read all three newspapers. 
8% read A and B, 5% read A and C, 4% read B and C.

Therefore 
(8% - 2% = 6%) read A and B and don't read C.

You can similarly compute : 
how many read A and C and don't read B 
how many read B and C and don't read A

Assume that you have done this: 
20% of the population read A, 16% read B, 14% read C

At this point, you should have been able to determine:
how many read all three
how many read A and B but not C 
how many read A and C but not B

Taking the above 3 percentages and deducting them from the 20% that read A, will give you the percentage of people that read A but do not read B or C.

You can similarly compute the number of people who read B but do not read A or C.

You can similarly compute the number of people who read C but do not read A or B.

At this point, you will have computed the percentage for 7 of the 8 categories.  Then the 8th category, how many people read none of the newpapers is simply 1 - (the sum of the 7 categories).

At this point it is **game over**.